# Javascript visibility hidden based on condition

Tags: javascript, forms

I would like to show and hide a text based on the length of the text in textbox. i have tried the following code. But its not working. Help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("fname");
            if(x.length<1)
                document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'visible';
            else
                document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'hidden';

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction()">

    <div id="lname" style="visibility:hidden">hey im printing</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not checking the length, instead you are checking whether the fname element does exist in current DOM or not.

Comment: I think you are checking for element count and not value length with `if(x.length<1)`

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/Ww4Pp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should check the input **value** length:

```
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
if(x.value.length<1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var x=document.getElementById("fname").value;
```

while assigning value to `var x`.

Comment: Your div tag will never appear on screen because when you are not entering anything in textbox then its onchange() method will not be called, that means your code in myFunction() method will not execute. It will come in myFunction() method only when you are entering somehhing in your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myFunction()
{
   var x=document.getElementById("fname").value;
   if(x.length>=1)
   {
      document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility="visible";
   }
   else
     document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npp76/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<div id="lname" style="visibility:hidden">hey im printing</div>

function myFunction()
{ 

       var x=document.getElementById("fname");
       if(x.value.length>0){
          document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }else{
           document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

}
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ww4Pp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check  this out using `jquery`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

//  var x=document.getElementById("fname").val();
var x=$("#fname").val();
    alert(x.length)
if(x.length < 1) {
    alert('if');
        $("#lname").css("display", "block");
}
//document.getElementById("lname").style.visibility = 'visible';
else {
    $("#lname").css("display", "none");
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction()">

<div id="lname" style="display:none">hey im printing</div>

</body>
</html>
```